# Executing a SQL statement, present in a table, and returning the resulting record set in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need help with a practical scenario. I have a table called CONFIG_TBL in Snowflake. This table has SQL statements, 1 per row. My goal is to use Snowflake Stored Procedures or Snowflake UDF, or  a combination of the two, and return a result set that will be obtained after execution of that statment.

The statements are simple select statements, like "select * from ABC'.

I could have done this, very easily in SQL server, since procedures can return table values. However, I don't know how to do this in Snowflake.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many rows will result from the selects? You cannot return tables from Snowflake stored procedures, but you can return delimited strings or variants with JSON up to 16 mb.

Comment: That is truly a limitation! The data I want to return is over 16mb.

Comment: Best thing to do in that case is write it to a temp table. Let me know if you want a code sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something to get you started at least. Procedures use javascript (SQL Stored Procedures are coming soon), but they can be used to run dynamic queries like you are looking for.

You can get the results in a couple of ways. By either returning a variant object or by using result_scan after calling the procedure.

This example just runs one query so your final solution will be different depending on just what you want the output to look like.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SCHEMA.PROCEDURE_NAME()
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS $$
retrieve_queries_sql = "select top 1 query from CONFIG_TBL";
retrieve_queries_result_set = snowflake.execute({sqlText: retrieve_queries_sql });

query_to_run = retrieve_queries_result_set.next().getColumnValue(1);

rs = snowflake.execute({sqlText: query_to_run})

var return_value = "";
if (rs.next())  {
      return_value += rs.getColumnValue(1);
      return_value += ", " + rs.getColumnValue(2);
      }
while (rs.next())  {
      return_value += "\n";
      return_value += rs.getColumnValue(1);
      return_value += ", " + rs.getColumnValue(2);
      }
  }
return return_value;
$$

CALL SCHEMA.PROCEDURE_NAME()

SELECT *
FROM table(result_scan(last_query_id()))
```

Edit: Fixed to have example correctly return a result which can then be used by the result_scan. Example taken from [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#using-result-scan-to-retrieve-the-result-from-a-stored-procedure). There are various more examples for getting results out of a procedure, including using JSON output.

Comment: It doesn't appear that queries run inside a stored procedure are accessible using result_scan. It will generate an error Statement <id> not found. The way to go would be to create a temp table because that will survive for the life of the session.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot a piece of the code. took this example from the Snowflake Docs.

Comment: Ah... I see what they're doing in the example. They're using the result_scan to grab and use the output of the stored procedure. This still limits the output to 16mb and is not table-based. It would be nice to reference the result_scan of queries run inside the stored procedure (vs. the output as in this example), but for some reason that does not work.

Comment: it can work if you execute as caller, but you might need to use last_query_id(-1) or get the query_id in another way.

Comment: Hi @DavidGarrison, Thank you so much for the valuable inputs. The last_query_id(-1), (-2 in my case) seems to be working exactly as I wanted, using that in result_scan is giving me the thing I needed. Brilliant solution.

From your inputs, the solution seems to be as follows..

Call stored_proc(inputs);

SELECT *
FROM table(result_scan(last_query_id(-2)));

Comment: @GregPavlik thank you so much for your inputs as well. You both are awesome!
This was my first time asking on StackOverflow, and I think I should have done so sooner.

Comment: If you are going to use result_scan that way, you can probably get rid of the whole return_value thing in the procedure. result_scan() is definitely a neat feature that can be used in other situations too. Worth playing around with it. The Snowflake docs on it are decent too. 
Good luck. And make sure to accept good answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

We can use language as SQL and return the value to table, Which can return table values.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DDL_TEST_SQL()
RETURNS TABLE(CARRIERFILEID integer, BLOBPATH varchar)
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
$$
DECLARE
    QUERY STRING;
    res resultset;

BEGIN

   QUERY := 'SELECT TOP 10 CARRIERFILEID,BLOBPATH from CONFIG.CARRIERFILE';
    res := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :QUERY);
return table(res);
END;
$$;
```

`CALL DDL_TEST_SQL()`